# Compare the date only of a datetime to current date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My meetings model has a dateTime field called meeting_date. I'd like to use it in a .where(...) query in a way such as this:

```
<% @meetings = Meeting.where(meeting_date.to_date == Date.today.to_s %>
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the CAST method of your DB system:

```
Meeting.where('CAST(meeting_date AS DATE) = ?', Date.current)
```

Or eventually:

```
Meeting.where(meeting_date: Date.current.beginning_of_day..Date.current.end_of_day)
```

To get all Meetings having the meeting date between today's date at 00:00:00 and today at 23:59:59

Comment: The 2nd piece of code worked, thanks so much ! Will accept when it allows me to.

Comment: You can also write: `Meeting.where(meeting_date: Time.current.all_day)`

Answer (score 0):

you should do:
    <% @meetings = Meeting.where(meeting_date: Date.today.to_datetime..(Date.today+1.day-1.minute).to_datetime) %>